# Can someone explain Lestrade's joke in "The Six Thatchers"?

Tags: dialogue, sherlock

In series 4 episode 1 of the TV series Sherlock, *The Six Thatchers*,  when John, Sherlock and Lestrade are in the Wellsburough's mansion and Sherlock is on a video call with Mary he tells her "All people are stupid... Most people." and then Lestrade says "Bizarre enough though, isn't it, to be him? I mean, it's right up your strasse." adding a slight selfish smile as if he's continuing the joke they had with John about Sherlock being exactly like a baby. Only I don't get it. Can someone explain it to me, please?

Comment: I can't help feeling that the "him" is a reference to *Moriarty*...but the sequence isn't quite right...it's as though there's been something edited out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he meant it's right up John's street since he's been dealing with a baby and strasse (Starbe) is street/road in German. Sherlock meant Mary wasn't stupid as she has tricked him in the past.